# Prerelease builds missing on iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect

Although I can upload successfully new versions of my app to iTunes Connect, I can't see them nor the previous ones under the "Prerelease" section in the app's page. Instead, I get a message saying "Upload your builds with Xcode 5.1.1 or later, or with Application Loader 3.0 or later". In the "Versions" tab, under "Builds", when I press the "+" button, I get an error saying my request couldn't be processed. Am I missing some needed configuration?

Comment: I have same problem right now. So I must wait for Apple to fix this or is there something I can do?

Comment: That's what I had to do. I contacted support, but they replied 2 days after. After 2 hours or so, everything went back to normal.

Comment: Today it happened again  :-((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is an issue with iTunes Connect, not something you did. There are a bunch of tweets right now of others experiencing the same issue.

What you'll see right now if you look at the itunesconnect hastag on Twitter:

> Our list of pre releases in #itunesconnect disappeared for no
>   reason... /cc @APPLEOFFIClAL 0 retweets 0 favorites 38m ago
>
> Weird…all of my app builds have disappeared from iTunes Connect
>   itunesconnect 1h ago
>
> itunesconnect: (slow / misbehavin') for everyone or just me (dot tumblr dot com) 2hours ago
>
> itunesconnect - no earlier uploaded binaries are seen in any application. Seems like a bug. Fix it Apple, I have to deliver to customers.

---

Unfortunately, the [official system status](https://developer.apple.com/system-status/) says everything is green. It's not clear how you're supposed to report an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it was an apple bug. After two hours, the prerelease builds appeared again.